# How to install Java jdk 8 from command line?

Tags: java, installation, java-8

I have search many places but didn't get proper details how to install from command line.

Please let me know how we can install JDK 8 from command line with example.

Comment: Should we assume my mean on Windows since you mention a "command line", who knows?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_enhancements.html#E1096849

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're installing on Windows, you can use the following:

> Install the public JRE in silent mode :
>
> ```
> jdk.exe /s
> ```
>
> Install development tools and source code in silent mode but not the
>   public JRE
>
> ```
> jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"
> ```
>
> Install development tools, source code, and the public JRE in silent
>   mode
>
> ```
> jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature"
> ```
>
> Install the public JRE in the specified directory C:\test\ in silent
>   mode
>
> ```
> jdk.exe /s /INSTALLDIRPUBJRE=C:\test\
> ```

You can find more details on the [source article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#jdk-silent-installation).